# How to serialize object with List inside in C# using XElement?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xelement

I have object with members of different types like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Str1 = string.Empty;
    public MyEnums.Enum1 E1 = MyEnums.Enum1.Unknown;
    public bool Done = false;
};
```

I have `Dictionary` of these objects:

```
Dictionary<string, MyObject> MyObjectsDic = new Dictionary<string, MyObject>();
```

And serializer for it like this:

```
public static void ToXml(string file, string collectionName, Dictionary<string, object> collection)
{
    XElement root = new XElement(collectionName);

    root.Add(collection.Select(x => new XElement("Item", new XAttribute("Object", x.Key),
            x.Value.GetType().GetFields().Select(f => new XElement(f.Name, f.GetValue(x.Value))))));

    root.Save(file);
}
```

The serializer tooks abstract `Dictionary` as argument and I need to convert my `MyObjectsDic` manually. May be I mistaken here.

```
ToXml("MyFile.xml", "MyObjects", MyObjectsDic.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => (object)p.Value));
```

I used [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554186/how-to-serialize-deserialize-to-dictionaryint-string-from-custom-xml-not-us) to make the serializer. It works good, but I need to add to MyObject new member

```
List<MyEnums.Enum2> Codes = new List<MyEnums.Enum2>();
```

And store some values here

```
var a = new MyObject {...};
a.Codes.Add(MyEnums.Enum2.Code1);
a.Codes.Add(MyEnums.Enum2.Code2);
MyObjectsDic.Add("Obj1", a);
```

But these list is serialized into file like

```
<Codes>Code1Code2<Codes/>
```

Without any space or delimiter. And I don't know how to make it more readable without modifications in serializer and without adding new odd code. The only idea I got is to keep already prepared string in MyObject instead of List<...>. It isn't graceful, but simple and works. I don't read these data, just only write and save as log into file.
Or I need to change my so cool serializer?

**Upd.**

I used the solution below, but I'm receiving an **exception** on Windows XP. On other OS's it works good. I modified code to make it like helper not an class extension.

```
Exception during dumping MyObjectsDic: There was an error reflecting type 'MyObject'.  
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportElement(TypeModel model, XmlRootAttribute root, String defaultNamespace, RecursionLimiter limiter)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(Type type, XmlRootAttribute root, String defaultNamespace)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type)
at MyXmlSerializerHelper.SerializeToXElement[T](T obj, XmlSerializer serializer, Boolean omitStandardNamespaces) in MyXmlSerializerHelper.cs:line 16
at MyXmlSerializerHelper.  <SerializeToFile>b__0[T](KeyValuePair'2 x) in MyXmlSerializerHelper.cs:line 5
```

The only idea I have - different versions of framework or some other religious issues on XP... Unfortunately, I can't install any other software or .Net version in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than attempting to use reflection to manually serialize your `MyObject` class, you can use [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to serialize your dictionary values directly to an `XElement` using the following methods, then include the result in the element tree you are building:

```
public static class XObjectExtensions
{
    public static XElement SerializeToXElement<T>(this IDictionary<string, T> collection, string collectionName)
    {
        return new XElement(collectionName, collection.Select(x => new XElement("Item", new XAttribute("Object", x.Key), x.Value.SerializeToXElement().Elements())));
    }

    public static XElement SerializeToXElement<T>(this T obj, XmlSerializer serializer = null, bool omitStandardNamespaces = true)
    {
        var doc = new XDocument();
        using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
        {
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = null;
            if (omitStandardNamespaces)
                (ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces()).Add("", ""); // Disable the xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd lines.
            (serializer ?? new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType())).Serialize(writer, obj, ns);
        }
        var element = doc.Root;
        if (element != null)
            element.Remove();
        return element;
    }
}
```

This automatically causes all fields and properties of `MyObject` to be serialized properly.  Using this, the resulting XML will look like:

> ```
> <MyObjects>
>   <Item Object="Obj1">
>     <Str1>Test object</Str1>
>     <E1>Unknown</E1>
>     <Done>false</Done>
>     <Codes>
>       <Enum2>Code1</Enum2>
>       <Enum2>Code2</Enum2>
>     </Codes>
>   </Item>
> </MyObjects>
> ```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! I can't understand a magic is going there, and difference, but it works.

Comment: I got an exception on.... Windows XP. On other systems works good. I've updated my question.

Comment: @Jury - 1) Was there an inner exception or additional message?  2) Try installing any patches or updates on that XP machine.  The latest version of .Net for XP is version 4 which should be fine.  3) Can you share the class which is causing the exception?

Comment: 1) It was inner exception  
2) I can't install anything in these machines
3) Unfortunately, I don't have yet access to this code.
I made so: on XP is used serializer as I posted in question, on other OS's - your solution. Percentage of XP is small, so it is not so critical, but, yep, not graceful.