# Cannot serialize member ... of type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 because it implements IDictionary

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, datacontractserializer

I am trying to pass a class with a Dictionary property over WCF and it is failing for one method but works for another.   When the class is returned inside a `List`, it works.  But when the class is returned inside a `DataTable`, the client just says the connection was disconnected and no error shows up.

Here is the class causing issues:

```
[DataContract]
public class DetailLog
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string SubAction
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Fields
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string UserName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I started out creating a method that works without issue:

```
public List<DetailLog> GetDetailLog(List<int> IDs, List<int> actionTypeIds, List<int> userIds, DateTime beginDate, DateTime endDate)
```

Then we needed to create some very dynamic reports so I used a DataTable which we have used previously for other dynamic reports.

But I needed to pass along the DetailLog class so I created a DataTable column of that type:

```
public DataTable GetCustomDetailReport(int CustomReportID, List<CustomReportFilter> reportFilters)
{
DataTable data = new DataTable();
...
data.Columns.Add("DetailLog", typeof(DetailLog));
...
}
```

This method would would exit fine on the WCF host side but the client side would error about the connection being lost. I tried adding ServiceKnownType for the OperationContract in the interface but it did not fix it:

```
[OperationContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(DetailLog))]
DataTable GetCustomUserAuditReport(int CustomReportID, List<CustomReportFilter> reportFilters);
```

I cannot really debug the serialization when the method returns the DataTable so I added this code to the end of the GetCustomDetailReport() to catch the error.

```
DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(DataTable), new List<Type> { typeof(DetailLog) });
ser.WriteObject(Stream.Null, data);
```

When I did, I saw an exception

> ```
> Cannot serialize member ... of type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 because it implements IDictionary.
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is as follows:

1. `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is supported by the [data contract serializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731072%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) used in WCF, as explained in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  This is why your `DetailLog` class can be sent over the wire successfully by WCF as a root object.
2. This serializer also supports [`IXmlSerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(v=vs.110).aspx) to allow types to manually serialize themselves to XML.
3. [`DataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implements `IXmlSerializable`.
4. Internally, `DataTable` serializes non-primitive entries *using [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)* -- a completely different serializer that uses a completely different code base.
5. [`XmlSerializer` does not support dictionaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx).  Thus your `DetailLog` cannot be sent over the wire by WCF *when nested in a `DataTable`*.
6. As an unrelated problem, you also need to set the data table name, serialization will throw an exception if you do not:

   ```
       data.TableName = "CustomDetailReport"; // For instance
   ```

To work around the issue with dictionaries, you need to make your `DetailLog` class serializable by both serializers.  The question [How to serialize/deserialize to `Dictionary<int, string>` from custom XML not using XElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554186/how-to-serialize-deserialize-to-dictionaryint-string-from-custom-xml-not-us) gives a variety of ways to serialize its dictionary property, including using a proxy array property:

```
[XmlType("KeyValue"), XmlRoot("KeyValue")]
public class SerializableKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>
{
    public TKey Key { get; set; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }
}

public static class SerializableKeyValuePairExtensions
{
    public static SerializableKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> ToSerializablePair<TKey, TValue>(this KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> pair)
    {
        return new SerializableKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> { Key = pair.Key, Value = pair.Value };
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class DetailLog
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string SubAction { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Fields { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [XmlArray("Fields")]
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    public SerializableKeyValuePair<string, string>[] FieldsArray
    {
        get
        {
            return Fields == null ? null : Fields.Select(p => p.ToSerializablePair()).ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            Fields = value == null ? null : value.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
        }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

WCF should now be able to send your `DataTable` over the wire successfully.

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough explanation!