# Add wcf reference: the file Reference.cs can not generate [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="ClassName", Namespace="..."]

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization, visual-studio-2013

Add wcf reference: the file Reference.cs can not generate [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="ClassName", Namespace="..."] but generate [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="...")] on top of a className(DataContract). For example:
[image]
but I want to let Reference.cs generate the below code:

[image]

How to do it?
if it is  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="...")] , wcf transfer parameter ClassName's instance cause ClassName's Int32 FieldName = 0.
but if it is [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="ClassName", Namespace="..."], wcf transfer parameter ClassName's instance can get correct value.

How to resolve it?

My server interface：

[image]

My model ：

[image]

Comment: Your WSDL is not "compatible" with DataContractSerilizer. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923(v=vs.110).aspx - it falls back on XmlSerializer

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But My Model is [DataContract], why auto-generate XmlTypeAttribute, how to resolve it ?

Comment: Also, please remove the screenshots of code and put the actual code in the question. It's very difficult to read.

Comment: The specific reason `XmlSerializer` is getting used instead of `DataContractSerializer` for your `UserPrivilegeInfo` type when contained in a `DataTable` inside a `DataSet` is explained in [Cannot serialize member … of type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 because it implements IDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34445868/3744182).

Comment: @dbc, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataContract` serializer is the default for WCF. There are several possible reasons why XML serializer is used in your case:

1. If the schema is not compatible with the DataContractSerializer, the XmlSerializer is selected. Check this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901(v=vs.110).aspx) for details.
2. Attribute XmlSerializerFormat is applied on the service

Could you check whether one of above points is your case?
If it doesn't work for you, please provide definitions for `UserPrivilegeInfo` and your service contract (both interface and implementing class)

**UPDATE:**

Ok, now we've identified that forced use of XmlSerializer was caused by returned DataSet.

It's generally a bad practice to return DataSet from WCF service.
These articles explain why:

[Returning DataSets from WebServices is the Spawn of Satan and Represents All That Is Truly Evil in the World](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReturningDataSetsFromWebServicesIsTheSpawnOfSatanAndRepresentsAllThatIsTrulyEvilInTheWorld.aspx)

[Why returning dataset or data table from WCF service is not a good practice? What are the Alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874224/why-returning-dataset-or-data-table-from-wcf-service-is-not-a-good-practice-wha)

Consider returning [DTO](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) (Data transfer object) instead of messy DataSet. You just fill DTO fields from the DataSet and transfer DTO to the client. The client accesses the data through strongly typed DTO by fields like `Id`, `Name`, etc.

In your case redefine method `GetCenterWebUser()` in the following way:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class CenterWebUser
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        //  Other fields for the user
    }

    public class SomeService : ISomeService
    {
        public CenterWebUser GetCenterWebUser()
        {
            DataSet ds = ...;

            var userTable = ds.Tables["Users"];
            var userRow = userTable.Rows[0];

            return new CenterWebUser()
            {
                Name = userRow.Field<string>("Name"),
                Email = userRow.Field<string>("Email")
                // ...
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have upload my server interface and model? could you help me?Thanks！

Comment: In the picture, UserPrvilegeInfo info is cut. Is DownloadNum the last field in this DataContract? Is it possible to copy/paste real code snippets, not the code screenshots?

Comment: Thnak you very much!

Comment: @CodeFuller - so my initial suspicion was correct. Go me! However, I +1'd you because your answer is clearly superior, and because you linked to the spawn of satan article. Apples, or a box with a picture of apples on it?

Comment: @tom redfern,  Thanks for all of you! I have learned a lot about all of you!

Answer (score 2):

You are using a DataSet as a return type. This is almost certainly the reason why WCF is falling back to the XmlSerializer rather than using the DataContractSerializer.

The DataContractSerializer has a strict set of [rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923(v=vs.110).aspx) about the types it supports for serialisation, and an even stricter set of [rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733112.aspx) around what XSD it supports. By including exposing a DataSet across your service boundary you are almost certainly violating these rules.

1. Remove the DataSet.
2. You're golden!

The other thing - why does it even matter to you whether the declarative attribute on your service reference says XmlTypeAttribute or DataContractAttribute? This should not matter to a consumer.

Do you have access to the service code? If I were you I would drop the service reference altogether and just consume the service directly using `ChannelFactory<T>`. Service references are [complex, unpredictable, indirect, and often do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41939631/569662).

Once you've removed the ludicrous DataSet from the return type, of course.

Comment: In pasted code there is no DataSet member in DataContract. Moreover, I've created test WCF service returning DataContract with DataSet field, and it's serialized with DataContract serializer by default.

Comment: @CodeFuller have you tried it with an operation returning a dataset?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it as in Superman's code.

Comment: @tom redfern,  Great! I have removed DataSet , it works and it's serialized with DataContract serializer. But I need to return DataSet type, how to resolve it?

Comment: @CodeFuller, how did you test returning DataSet type in interface? Could you help me?

Comment: Check my answer update.