# How to deserialize XML into specific structure (where containing collection)

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Below is the XML:

```
<columninfo name="f1config">
    <column name="col1,col2" fieldname="c1" type="string" />
    <column name="col3" fieldname="c3" type="date" format="ddMMMyyy"/>
    <column name="col4,col5" fieldname="c4" type="string" format="ddMMMyyy"/>
 </columninfo>
```

How to deserialize above into below class `columninfo`:

```
public class columninfo
{
 public string name {get;set;}
 public Dictionary<string,column> fieldList {get;set;}
}

public class column
{
  public string name {get;set;}
  public string fieldname {get;set}
  public string format {get;set;}
}
```

problem is for collection object - `fieldList`.

Comment: with your current XML you cannot do this. You can verify it by yourself by going to **Visual Studio >> Edit >> Paste Special >> Paste XML as Classes**. There you'll see that the class hierarchy which you is defined is not like as generated by visual studio

Comment: I've just done that, it shows XML - column array. But need `dictionary<name,column>`.

Comment: There are plenty of questions of how to serialize/deserialize dictionary if that is the question (e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12554186/1997232)). As for your question you can always [manually parse](http://stackoverflow.com/q/55828/1997232) xml.

Comment: Is it poss with both - dictionary and name property -  `public string name {get;set;}
 public Dictionary<string,column> fieldList {get;set;}`  as how above XML?

Comment: @dsi you'll have to look at Sinatr comment then .. Otherwise there is no solution by doing it with standard XML parsing. You'll have to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication48
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            columninfo.info = doc.Descendants("columninfo").Select(x => new columninfo() {
                name = (string)x.Attribute("name"),
                fieldList = columninfo.GetDictionary(x)
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
    public class columninfo
    {
        public static List<columninfo> info = new List<columninfo>();
        public string name {get;set;}
        public Dictionary<string,column> fieldList {get;set;}

        public static Dictionary<string,column> GetDictionary(XElement columninfo)
        {
            Dictionary<string,column> dict = new Dictionary<string,column>();

            foreach(XElement column in columninfo.Elements("column"))
            {
                string fieldname = (string)column.Attribute("fieldname");
                string _type = (string)column.Attribute("type");
                string name = (string)column.Attribute("name");

                column newCol;
                string[] names;
                switch(fieldname)
                {
                    case "c1" :
                        names = name.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                        newCol = new column() { name = names[0], format = _type, fieldname = fieldname };
                        dict.Add("c1", newCol);
                        newCol = new column() { name = names[1], format = _type, fieldname = fieldname };
                        dict.Add("c2", newCol);
                        break;

                    case "c3":
                        newCol = new column() { name = fieldname, format = _type, fieldname = fieldname };
                        dict.Add("c3", newCol);
                        break;

                    case "c4":
                        names = name.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                        newCol = new column() { name = names[0], format = _type, fieldname = fieldname };
                        dict.Add("c4", newCol);
                        newCol = new column() { name = names[1], format = _type, fieldname = fieldname };
                        dict.Add("c5", newCol);
                        break;
                }
            }

            return dict;
        }
    }

    public class column
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string fieldname { get; set; }
        public string format { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. actually, have applied answer as added above.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken in two stage, 1) deserialize to object containing array and 2) then by linq converting to dictionary.

Thanks