# How to deserialize XML with repeating tag name with unique identifier as attribute?

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I am trying to deserialize this xml where all the node has the same name with a unique identifier as an attribute.

```
<configuration>
    <setting name="host">
        <value>127.0.0.1</value>
    </setting>
    <setting name="port">
        <value>80</value>
    </setting>
</configuration>
```

The result I am trying to achieve is:

```
public class Configuration
{
    string host { get; set; }
    int port { get; set; }
}
```

I read the previous question and I am still stumbling with the fact they have the same tag name.

Thank you!

Comment: I think I found a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554186/how-to-serialize-deserialize-to-dictionaryint-string-from-custom-xml-not-us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("yourxmlhere");

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        XmlNode root = doc.FirstChild;
        if (root.HasChildNodes)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode item in root.ChildNodes)
            {
                configuration = SetValueByPropertyName(configuration, item.Attributes["name"].Value, item.FirstChild.InnerText);
            }
        }
```

The helper method to set values:

```
public static TInput SetValueByPropertyName<TInput>(TInput obj, string name, string value)
        {
            PropertyInfo prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(name);
            if (null != prop && prop.CanWrite)
            {
                if (prop.PropertyType != typeof(String))
                {
                    prop.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(value, prop.PropertyType), null);
                }
                else
                {
                    prop.SetValue(obj, value, null);
                }
            }
            return obj;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call this "old school" but it works.

1. Copy the XML (or fragment, etc) and leverage Visual Studio (2015(?) and up -  shot below is 2017 ) feature "Paste XML/JSON As Classes"

   [image: Visual Studio 2017]

   This helps tremendously with *valid XML* - particularly with the "proper" attributes that decorate the generated classes. Additionally, it's just a class, so you can customize it as you deem fit (while retaining the attributes).

   For more complex XML - such as namespaces/prefixes, you'll really appreciate this. If you don't have this tool, you can use [`XSD.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe) (even more old school) - does the same thing for XML documents.
2. Auto-generated Classes from above step:

   > ...stumbling with the fact they have the same tag name...

   Don't be. XML elements can repeat - often do (e.g. `sitemap.xml` of every web site out there). The generated class will help you grok it. It's a standard collection/array/list.

   ```
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
   public partial class configuration
   {

       private configurationSetting[] settingField;

       /// <remarks/>
       [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("setting")]
       public configurationSetting[] setting
       {
           get
           {
               return this.settingField;
           }
           set
           {
               this.settingField = value;
           }
       }
   }

   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
   public partial class configurationSetting
   {

       private string valueField;

       private string nameField;

       /// <remarks/>
       public string value
       {
           get
           {
               return this.valueField;
           }
           set
           {
               this.valueField = value;
           }
       }

       /// <remarks/>
       [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
       public string name
       {
           get
           {
               return this.nameField;
           }
           set
           {
               this.nameField = value;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Given the above, you can do this:

```
string rawXml = "<configuration><setting name=\"host\"><value>127.0.0.1</value></setting><setting name=\"port\"><value>80</value></setting></configuration>";

var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(configuration));
configuration config;
using (TextReader rdr = new StringReader(rawXml))
{
    config = (configuration)ser.Deserialize(rdr);
}


foreach (configurationSetting setting in config.setting)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{setting.name} = {setting.value}");
}
```

Output:

```
host = 127.0.0.1
port = 80
```

Hth..

Answer (score 1):

Load your xml as a doc

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(your_xml_data);
```

Then iterate through the child nodes

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
XmlNode root = doc.FirstChild;

//fill the configuration from the child nodes.
if (root.HasChildNodes)
{
 if(root.ChildNodes[0].Name == "host")
 {
    configuration.host = root.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
 }
 if(root.ChildNodes[1].Name == "port")
 {   
    configuration.port = root.ChildNodes[1].InnerText;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank, in this code, there is an assumption about the sorting that I cannot remove without a lot code like if name == "host"

Comment: updated to check the name of the child nodes and update the correct field